# Render special characters in placeholder JSX

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a multilingual site and having great difficulty finding a way to render special characters as placeholder text in an input. Any way I try that is specified in the react docs, directly writing the Unicode character, converting the HTML entity to String.fromCharCode(xx), it does not seem to render correctly. Some symbols are working correctly, like the registered trade mark, but characters with accents like É will just show as E. Example below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder={`R${String.fromCharCode(233)}SERVER`} />
```

Has anyone faced this issue, or have an idea of how we can get around it?

Cheers!

Comment: Does it work if you store `String.fromCharCode(233)` in a variable and then template string the variable in? I'm wondering if the second set of braces is getting interpreted incorrectly

Answer (score 4):

Write your `jsx` code wrapped in `{` `}` as shown below:

```
<h1>Code {'É'}</h1>
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks! Just edited my question. The characters render fine anywhere except in placeholder text for an input.